# Check if user is banned (Laravel)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm creating a filter in my route to check if a user is banned, but I can't find a way to check it.

I'm using a table named 'bans' with 'id', 'userid' and 'reason' in it, userid is linked to the id of the user, located in the 'users' table.

I'm using this code in my routes:

```
    Route::filter('banned', function()
{
        $banned = Banned::select('userid');
    if ( Banned::select('userid')->where('userid', Auth::id()) )
    {
        return Redirect::to('/banned')->with('users', Auth::user());
    }
});
```

It is supposed to return the user to the /banned page if the id from the active user appears in the bans table (under userid).

My code does nothing.

Could someone help me with this one?

Thanks in advance,

Sincerely,

Arne.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What error you get? What result you get and what is expected?

Comment: Added to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( Banned::where('userid', Auth::user()->id)->get()->count() > 0 )
```

Comment: I've just checked this code and it works.  It seems you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I chose to make a new column in my users table named 'isbanned' and use a join in my function.